# Check checkbox in handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am using the below code to check my checkbox in handlebars.

```
  <fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="control-label">{{#t "display_creators_name"}}Display Creator's name{{/t}}</div>
      <div class="controls">
        <label class="checkbox" for="creators_name">
          {{checkbox "creators_name"
            checked=creators_name}}
          {{#t "allow_creators_name"}}{{/t}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
```

But the checkbox is not checked.

Can someone please help me for the same.

Comment: are you using the [handlebars-form-helpers](https://github.com/badsyntax/handlebars-form-helpers)?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli No

Comment: As far as i know there is no native `checkbox` helper in handlerbars, so what is the `{{checkbox ...}}` supposed to do?

Comment: I am using some existing application and they have used this way only for another checkbox and its working

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli For reference: https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/blob/stable/app/views/jst/DiscussionTopics/EditView.handlebars

Comment: I think the existing app must also have defined some helpers..check for it

Comment: I am using https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/blob/stable/app/views/jst/DiscussionTopics/EditView.handlebars